# Migration to PHPUnit9 equalTo with Delta and Canonicalizing

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I try to migrate an old PHPUnit Test to PHPUnit9 and have the following case now:

```
$mockObject
  ->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
  ->method('someMethod')
  ->withConsecutive(
      [
         $this->equalTo($object, 1, 10, true), 'some other parameters'
      ]
   );
```

And now I want migrate this to PHPUnit9 but I found no solution for combine the delta parameter and the canonicalizing parameter. For the delta I can use change the `equalTo` to `equalToWithDelta`, for the canonicalizing I can change the  `equalTo` to `equalToWithCanonicalizing`, but I need to combine this two to get the same behaviour and don't find anything for that in PHPUnit9.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, the `$canonicalize` parameter does not have any effect on numbers. And `$delta` only has an effect on numbers. So just use `equalToWithDelta()`.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't solve the problem. I think the main problem is that the test is not well written and use properly some site effects. In the object we have a DateTime for that we need the delta. But there are also some object hashes in it, that get lost when we canonicalize it with the canonicalize parameter. I change  the `$this->equalTo($object, 1, 10, true)` to `new IsEqual($object, 1, true).` That solve the problem for now, but I think I must rewrite the test in a different way later.